# Get rid of in-document text panel?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, typesetting

Every single time I use the typeface tool now and try to shift or highlight, I get this weird grey panel with extra character options I don't want and will never need. How do I make that disappear forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>CLTR</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- Preferences
- Type tab
- Untick the `Enable type layer glyph alternates`
- https://youtu.be/S7A6A_je1tA

Comment: Thank you! <insert proxy text to fill blank space for no reason>